# RPi Camera starts going white

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, raspicam, picamera

I bought a RPi Camera V2 from amazon yesterday and when I tested it today it started going white and then flashing colors like a disco party (rave starts 8 seconds in):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHN10.jpg

All I did was record a video and convert it into .mp4:

```
$ raspivid -o myvid.h264 -t 30000 -w 1280 -h 720 -b 8000000
$ MP4Box -fps 30 -add myvid.h264 myvid.mp4
```

The same thing is happening before I convert it to mp4 and with different resolutions and bitrates set. I've also tried every single exposure, AWB, and image effect mode but the result is the same.

Does anyone know whats happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Repeat your test with the camera lying still on the table, to exclude connector glitches. If the issue persists, try to send it back as broken.

Comment: What power supply are you using with the Pi?  Do you have access to another cable to test with?  Try to reseat the cable, see what happens.

Comment: @mrSidX, I'm powering the Pi with my laptop using the micro USB cable. I've tried swapping out the power cable but the issue persists. I have a feeling the issue is with the camera, so I'll try to get my hands on another one and test it. Thanks

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, I just tried that out and the result is the same. I think the camera is just defective. I'll probably just end up returning it. Thanks

Comment: What laptop? Not all laptops provide extra power out of the USB ports.  Some exceptions are some Mac Air products that are beefed up to power external Optical (SuperDrives)...  There is a chance your USB power out Amperage is not high enough.   It might only provide 1A, which if so, is not enough to power the Pi when it is running extra components like your Camera.

I would setup the Pi for headless access, attach to a beefy power supply or powered USB hub 3A (2.1A at the least!)

ssh into it with your laptop.

Eliminate the power/cable issue first, then return if issue persists.